# Godex 730 rastertoezpl driver in cups prints wrong orientation

Tags: cups

I recently updated from cups 1.4 (Centos 6) to cups 1.6 (Centos 7). I am using Godex label printers and the rastertoezpl printer driver offered by Godex. Anyway since the update one printer (where the label has bigger height than width) prints wrong oriented while the other printer (where the label has a bigger width than height) prints correctly.

But there are no options to set PageOrientation in the PPD file.
How can I get rid of this issue which did not appear before the update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the size of the label in the cups web interface using the page size "custom" setting was the source of the problem.

To make CUPS stop rotating the orientation without any logical sense, I had to first add the label size to the PPD file and then use the cups webinterface to choose the already existing label size.

After following this procedure cups printed the labels in the right orientation.